# Problem setting up Raspberry Pi Zero 2w

Tags: ssh, pi-zero-w-2

I have a little problem setting up my Raspberry Pi Zero 2w. Since i don't have a micro HDMI cable, i wanted to set it up so that i can connect to it via ssh. This however did not work at all. I wanted to install the normal raspbian OS with the Imager. I put my WIFI Information in the Imager and enabled ssh. After Inserting the SD-Card Into my PI and turning it on, a green LED lights up. Now when i try to connect to the Pi, the host can't be found. Is there something else i need to do before being able to ssh onto the device?
Please help.

Comment: The Pi Zero uses a miniHDMI cable (a rather poor choice by the designers). Raspbian is meaningless; what OS did you install and how did you configure it - unless you set a user and password you need a screen and keyboard.

Comment: Oh right yeah it's called miniHDMI. Sorry that was my bad. I used the Raspberry Pi OS (Legacy 32-bit) option, basically the first that was given when installing the OS. I also set up a username and a passwort. I didnt tick the box with "Hostname" next to it. Was that maybe the problem?

Comment: Does it connect to your router? What IP address is assigned?

Comment: It doesnt. Thats the problem. I dont see it listed in my devices on my router

Comment: Based on the (lack of) information no one can say what you have done or why it doesn't work. Setting up a headless system is challenging for experienced users and requires EVERYTHING to be setup perfectly. Obviously you have not setup networking correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not showing up on your routers connected devices list, it's not connected. Something has gone wrong with connecting to the router or the credentials are incorrect. I looked at what WiFi bands the zero 2w and it only supports 2.4GHz. Perhaps your router is configured for 5GHz band. As Milliways pointed out earlier, there's not much information you've provided.